# Does adding a new data file (without partitioning) have any pro/con compared to increasing space on existing data file?

Tags: sql-server, datafile

I have a database data file with 1 data file in the default filegroup. It is reaching to 500GB in size and I'm trying to learn about whether to increase the size of existing data file or add a new data file.

If I add a new file into the default file group, then SQL engine will use round robin/proportional fill algorithm to fill data extents into the files.

Assuming partitioning isn't used, disk space limit isn't an issue, and also IO latency is acceptable, then there is no benefit to having a separate data file because even one data file can technically be read in parallel, irrespective of whether the files are on same or separate drive.

Is this correct understanding?

Comment: https://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/what-is-filegroup-in-sql-server-when-to.html

Comment: I don't think this is correct because there is nothing stopping the SQL engine from using multiple data access threads even if there is only one data file.

Comment: This IS correct, the similar thing you'll see when you backup your database in 1 file vs multiple files, try it and you'll be surprised.

Comment: @sepupic - backup I believe is generally single threaded, and if you stripe it to multiple backup files then it becomes multi threaded. But this concept has no relation to the data file access threads. There is nothing preventing SQL engine from using parallel threads to access the data file during normal operations AFAIK.

Comment: "Put different tables used in the same join queries in different filegroups. This step will improve performance, because of parallel disk I/O searching for joined data."   source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: "Put heavily accessed tables and the nonclustered indexes that belong to those tables on different filegroups. Using different filegroups will improve performance, because of parallel I/O if the files are located on different physical disks." - the same source